Playwright - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' - external npm package
I have created npm package in order to use it withing our organization. It containing some reusable code for testing. It is published to our internal feed and i have installed in destination project without any problems.
Destination project containing playwright tests and when im trying to run them it started to show me error while im trying to import anything from that npm package:
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export
In this project im using node.js 20 and typescript, i have installed babel and configured  to use typescript presets. In my tsconfig i also set to  "module": "ESNext", however i have still this issue. My npm package have actually same configuration. Im bit lost what is missing here.
tsconfig
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react",
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "target": "ESNext",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {}
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*",".vscode/babel.config.js"]
}

babel config
module.exports = {
    presets: [
      [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          targets: {
            node: 'current',
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };

i also included this in package.json
    "jest": {
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "/node_modules/(?!(somePkg)|react-dnd|core-dnd|@react-dnd)"
          ]
    },


I don't see any obvious problems here other than the partial package.json (invalid syntax). Can you provide complete, full, runnable code that reproduces the problem? Thanks.

I've faced the same issue, I think the problem is within Playwright and the way it compiles/transpiles... The way I solved it was to make sure my package didn't include any .ts file other than .d.ts and it was packaged into commonjs so that the export keyword is not used. For that I made these changes that I think will work for you:
on packages.json I added:
scripts:{
...
    "build": "rm -rf dist; tsc",
...
},
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "README.md"
  ],

this guarantees we do the compilation and only what's inside dist is packaged.
on tsconfig.json I changed/added:
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "noEmit": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",

the way I tested if this was by doing npm build followed by npm pack then on the project I wanted to use this I installed the resulting tarball.
I'm not using babel so I'm not sure how that will interfere, but I hope this helps.
